# v-for with index on iterable collection vue js not recongnisable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm currently iterating from results of array of key value

```
data: {
  return {
    results: [
     [{id: 1, name: 'A1'}, {id: 2, name: 'B1'}, {id: 3, name: 'C1'}],
     [{id: 4, name: 'A2'}, {id: 5, name: 'B2'}, {id: 6, name: 'C2'}],
     [{id: 7, name: 'A3'}, {id: 8, name: 'B3'}, {id: 9, name: 'C3'}],
     [{id: 10, name: 'A4'}, {id: 11, name: 'B4'}],
    ]
  }
}
```

And I'm rending it using this

```
 <div v-for="(items, index) in results" :key="index">
   <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
     <v-card>
       <v-card-title>{{item.name}}</v-card-title>
     </v-card>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Is there a way I can exclude the rendering of parent `div`?

Comment: Yours is a nested array, you need a nested for loop.

Comment: @MatJ I tried the nested array before and but the layout becomes wrong. Is there a way I can exclude the rendering of first div from nested loop? I updated by question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Another option:** If the outer parent `<div>` is not needed and is only used for iteration, `v-for` on `<template>` can be used to generate a block of multiple elements inside it (only renders dom elems inside it iteratively).

**When both iterative divs are not required**

```
<template v-for="(items, index) in results">
       <template v-for="item in items">
         <v-card>
           <v-card-title>{{item.name}}</v-card-title>
         </v-card>
       </template>
     </template>
```

**When the div parent immediate to `v-card` is not required:**

```
 <div v-for="(items, index) in results" :key="index">
   <template v-for="item in items">
     <v-card>
       <v-card-title>{{item.name}}</v-card-title>
     </v-card>
   </template>
 </div>
```

**++UPDATE++**

`key` binding can't be put on template for listing (iterating) because the way  it is used to track and diff between acutal DOM elements nodes.`Vue` itself gives a nice warning for that in console.

Comment: You'd also need to update all the keys. The `key` can't be placed on a `<template>` directly, it needs to be on the `<v-card>`.

Comment: @skirtle Whoa! good catch. Makes sense the way `key` binding works for actual dom nodes. I'll update the answer. But how would u update the key if you can't use it on `template`?

Answer (score 0):

### You have an array in array

so look at this, I am using v-for in v-for.

I changed both section.

```
data: {
  return {
    results: [
      [{id: 1, name: 'A1'}, {id: 2, name: 'B1'}, {id: 3, name: 'C1'}],
      [{id: 4, name: 'A2'}, {id: 5, name: 'B2'}, {id: 6, name: 'C2'}],
      [{id: 7, name: 'A3'}, {id: 8, name: 'B3'}, {id: 9, name: 'C3'}],
      [{id: 10, name: 'A4'}, {id: 11, name: 'B4'}]
    ]
  }
}
```

-

```
<div v-for="(items, idx) in results" :key="items[0].id">
  <v-card v-for="(item) in items" :key="item.id">
   <v-card-title>{{item.name}}</v-card-title>
  </v-card>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

data should be a method that return object with values just like below

```
data () {
  return {
    results: [
     [{id: 1, name: 'A1'}, {id: 2, name: 'B1'}, {id: 3, name: 'C1'}],
     [{id: 4, name: 'A2'}, {id: 5, name: 'B2'}, {id: 6, name: 'C2'}],
     [{id: 7, name: 'A3'}, {id: 8, name: 'B3'}, {id: 9, name: 'C3'}],
     [{id: 10, name: 'A4'}, {id: 11, name: 'B4'}],
    ]
  }
}
```